# Open File Explorer in Python, or focus if already open and in same directory

Tags: python, winapi

In Python I'd like to open a file explorer to a specific directory, or if it is already open in another window, bring focus to that window.  Currently I'm doing this:

```
os.startfile(path, 'explore')
```

But it opens as many File Explorers as calls to `os.startfile`.  Is it possible in Python to focus on an existing one?

Comment: You'll need to use [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) to interface with the appropriate Windows subsystem to find out what Windows Explorer windows are open, if any, and what directories they're currently focused on.

Comment: The shell API offers such functionality. No need for any hacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon this question looking for the exact opposite of what you want, to open the explorer multiple times on the same directory.

Coming from the documentation

[os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile)

> When operation is not specified or 'open', this acts like double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer, or giving the file name as an argument to the start command from the interactive command shell: the file is opened with whatever application (if any) its extension is associated.

so just doing

`os.startfile(path)`

or

`os.startfile(path, 'open')`

would do exactly what you want as long as the opened explorer is still in the directory you started with. I don't know if I am correct though as my answer assumes you are on win7 os and using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

For Python3 (Works for Mac and PC):

```
import platform


def showFileExplorer(file):  # Path to file (string)
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        import os
        os.startfile(file)
    elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
        import subprocess
        subprocess.call(["open", "-R", file])
    else:
        import subprocess
        subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", file])

showFileExplorer(os.path.abspath(file))
```

`